# Share a Library in Dependent Targets via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I write two applications and framework in one project, applications depend on my framework (Library). I use cocoapods to manage dependences in my project.
I link applications with library in the project's setting.
My Pod file:

```
use_frameworks!

target "Application1" do
        pod 'A'
        target "ApplicationTest" do
                inherit! :search_paths
        end
end

target "Application2" do
        pod 'A'
        target "ApplicationTest" do
                inherit! :search_paths
        end
end

target "Library" do
    pod 'B'
end
```

I've faced with problem. Pod 'B' depends on pod 'A', and after application launches, I have warning:

> Class APod_Class is implemented in both Application1 and Library.

I think, should be simple solution for that problem, but I can't find solution of that problem via cocoapods.
How I can solve that problem?